# How to correct citation count of a given paper in Google Scholar?

Tags: publications, citations, google-scholar

Two of my works have been recently cited by the same paper. The citation count of one of them was updated properly in Google Scholar, but not for the other one. What is weirder is that the references of this citing paper provide a working link to the Google Scholar entry of both works. So, I can open this citing paper, click on this reference entry, be redirected to the correct Google Scholar page, and see that the citing paper is not listed under "Cited by #".

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Are the two papers cited with their DOI? AFAIK, Google Scholar uses an 'automated system' for 'inputing' the citation count. At times, it takes time.

Comment: Well, none of the references of their paper is listed with their DOI in the PDF. Perhaps it is done under the hood, but I don't know.

Comment: Is the publication you are talking about very recent? If so, this could be due to a data updating delay.

Comment: Yes, it is. That makes sense, I will wait to see if it gets fixed!